# Silverlight: Does UserControl Have a Background Property?

Tags: silverlight, user-controls, background, properties

I created a `BarMenuItem` `UserControl` in a Silverlight class library, and try to used in my main Silverlight application.

BarMenuItem.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ButtonControlLibrary.BarMenuItem"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

</UserControl>
```

BarMenuItem.xmal.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ButtonControlLibrary
{
    public partial class BarMenuItem : UserControl
    {
        public BarMenuItem()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

So in the MainPage, I have `xmlns:blib="clr-namespace:ButtonControlLibrary;assembly=ButtonControlLibrary"` defined

Tried to use `BarMenuItem`:

```
<blib:BarMenuItem Width="100" Height="150" Background="Red"/>
```

Compile and run it, and I expected to see a Red background, but I see nothing.

What happenend?

I'm so confused.  I googled a lot, finding there is a workaround, but very ugly: Put a `Grid` container inside the `UserControl`, and then binding its `Background` property to the `UserControl`'s `Background`:

```
Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=guiUserControl}"
```

But this is not the solution.  Please advice.

In Adobe Flex, it's so natural to change a UserControl's background like what I do in the above code.

Am I missing anything?

Thanks.

Comment: Generally UserControls aren't all that good at create components such as "MenuItems" they are better at creating larger application specific composites.  Consider using a templated control instead, its a little more work but generates something much more like the typical SDK/Toolkit component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is there but it doesn't seem to work in Silverlight. Your next best bet is the solution you said you already know. Binding layoutroot's background with usercontrol's background.

Comment: Is this a Silverlight bug?  I just cannot believe it.  A property is there and we CANNOT use it.  What the hack?!

Comment: Yea call it a bug. I'm not sure if they did it deliberately.

Comment: A bug cannot be so funny.  It's so obvious that a developer will use it so often. Hmmm, Microsoft is doing something funny.

Comment: @Peter: This is not a bug.  The reality is that a `Control` actually has no UI at all hence the Silverlight runtime can't do anything with the Background property.  In the case of templated controls its up to the `ControlTemplate` to bind the `Background` property to an appropriate element.  In the case of a `UserControl` there is no template, its up to the derived class to do something appropriate with the background property itself, in conjunction with its own Xaml.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Not having a template is a bug. In WPF it works as it should. I don't see why Silverlight's UserControl can't have it?

Comment: @Hasan: it works in WPF as it should in __WPF__.  Silverlight is Silverlight.  Not having a template is clearly a design choice, one of the many many compromises Silverlight has had to make in order to deliver a small download footprint.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones that could be the reason.

Comment: +1 because the answer is correct so the downvote doesn't make sense to me.